# Will a joke bet be honored during Aakhirah (afterlife) if a person dies?

Tags: hadith, money, akhirah

I have heard in one jamaat that a person who takes debt from another person has to give good deeds during [Aakhirah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akhirah) if he dies without returning his amount.

Now my question is:  While playing or doing fun, if pose bets such as if India will win this match I will give you Rs.50 else you will give me. And after India loses we say that it was a joke.

So whether that losing bet will be consider at Akhiraah as debts and our deeds will be given in order to repay the amount?

Answer (score 3):

Praise Be to Allah.

First of all, betting is equivalent to **gambling**, and it is haraam in Islam.

Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala has said in the Qur'an:

> يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا إِنَّمَا الْخَمْرُ‌ وَالْمَيْسِرُ‌ وَالْأَنصَابُ وَالْأَزْلَامُ رِ‌جْسٌ مِّنْ عَمَلِ الشَّيْطَانِ فَاجْتَنِبُوهُ لَعَلَّكُمْ تُفْلِحُونَ

"O you who have believed, indeed, **intoxicants**, **gambling**, **[sacrificing on] stone alters [to other than Allah]**, and **divining arrows** are but defilement from the work of Satan, so avoid it that you may be successful." [5:90]

You've mentioned in your question that you were betting with a friend of yours about India's win/loss in a certain game. Considering the above verse from the Qur'an, this is definitley haraam, and you should never do such a thing, as a Muslim **must** abide by the Rules and Restrictions set by Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala , without any kinds of hesitations and without any kinds of questions/arguments. So you should try your level best to avoid such actions or situations. May Allah protect you from such sins, Ameen.

Secondly, with regards to the issue whether not paying the bet amount turns into debt or not, scholars have recommended that it's not permissible to pay the debt for something haraam. Hence, it is technically not a debt in Shaa Allah, since betting is haraam. So, at the first place, try your best not to pay it. But if you're somehow forced to pay it, then better pay it, and ask Allah Subhanahu Wa Ta'ala's forgiveness and sincerely repent and commit to never doing this again. For more details, please refer to this [link](http://islamqa.info/en/5980). And Allah knows best.

May Allah keep your faith strong, and keep you clean from debts, and let you die as a Muslim. Ameen.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and its not me....I just gave example of that if suppose context

Comment: Oh ... I'm sorry brother. May Allah keep you steadfast in His Deen. And please make du'a for me. :)